# Bootstrap online customizer use without SASS or LESS

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, customization

In the past the Bootstrap online customizer was straightforward and resulted in a download of static CSS and JS files. I do not use LESS or SASS. Is it possible for someone like me to customize BS online any more? I don't know what to do with the config.json file.

I realize I can override BS styles in a separate stylesheet but would like to start off with my own choice of colours for links etc

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can still use the Bootstrap Customizer to generate CSS files:

http://getbootstrap.com/customize/

Just edit the variables and click 'Compile and Download'.

You'll get a zip with CSS, font and js files inside. You'll also find a config.json file which you can upload and use to make changes to your custom bootstrap configuration later.

Comment: yes, I downloaded as you suggest and didn't get anything other than a config.json file. Now I know that isn't supposed to happen I'll try again.

Comment: Maybe use a different browser (Firefox or Chrome)? The customizer doesn't work properly in Safari.

Comment: The customizer doesn't work great in the latest Firefox either. Chrome it's working best.

Comment: I succeeded using Chrome having been using Firefox.